# Error on site using CI v 1.0

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a site build using Codeiginiter 1.0. It was crowdfunding site and using wepay auth. When user register it was redirect to wepay landing and after loging in to wepay it was redirect back to home page. But now an error appear.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$account_uri

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 114
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/x/e/b/xebragroup3/html/ext_domains/undercoverfunder/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 675
```

Here is home.php

```
    <?php  if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->model('home_model');
        $this->load->model('search_model');
        $this->load->helper('wepay');
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
    }


    function index()
   {

    $data['categories']= $this->home_model->getallCategories();
    $data['home_active']='active';
    $per_page = 12;     
                    if($this->uri->segment(3)==''){ $off = 0; }else{ $off = $this->uri->segment(3); }
                        $result = $this->home_model->count_getallprojects();
                        $base_url = base_url().'/home/index/';
                        $data['projects'] = $this->home_model->getallprojects($off,$per_page);
                        $config['uri_segment']          = '3';

                        $total  = count($result);

                            //code for pagging
                            $config['base_url']                 = $base_url;
                            $config['total_rows']           = $total;
                            $config['per_page']                 = $per_page;
                            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<span>';
                            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</span>';
                            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b>';
                            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>';
                            $config['first_link'] = '« First';
                            $config['last_link'] = ' Last »';
                            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<span>';
                            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</span>';
                            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
                            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<span>';
                            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</span>';
                            $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
                            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<span>';
                            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</span>';                          

                            $this->load->library('pagination',$result);
                            $this->pagination->initialize($config);                         

                        $this->load->view('frontend/home/home_view',$data);
    }

function wepay()
{
        if(isset($_GET['code']))
     {

                            $url = wepayurl.$_GET['code']; 
                            $ch = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
                            $response = curl_exec($ch);
                            curl_close($ch);
                            $response_r = json_decode($response);
                            if(isset($response_r))
                            {                           
                                if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())  {
                                            //before login  
                                            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('ses_userid_lf');   
                                            $user_fname= $this->session->userdata('ses_name_lf');
                                }
                                else    
                                {           //after login
                                            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
                                            $user_fname = $this->session->userdata('front_username');   
                                }                           

                                $data_wepay = array('user_id'=>$user_id,'wepay_user_id'=>$response_r->user_id,'wepay_user_access_token'=>$response_r->access_token);
                               $this->db->insert('wc_wepay_user_account_dtls',$data_wepay);


                                    $client_id = wepay_clientid;
                                $client_secret = wepay_scrite;      

                                    $access_token = $response_r->access_token;
                                // change to useProduction for live environments
                                    //Wepay::useStaging($client_id, $client_secret);
                                    Wepay::useProduction($client_id, $client_secret);
                                    $wepay = new WePay($access_token);
                                    $res = $wepay->request('account/create/', array(
                                            'name'          => $user_fname,
                                            'description'   => 'Subscribed to Letsfund.it.'
                                ));

                                    if(!empty($res))
                                    {

                                        if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())  { $user_id =  $this->session->userdata('ses_userid_lf');    }
                                        else    
                                        {   $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');}

                                        $currdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
                                        $data = array('account_uri'=>$res->account_uri,'account_id'=>$res->account_id,'dt_created'=>$currdate);
                                        $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);                                   
                                        $this->db->update('wc_wepay_user_account_dtls',$data);                                                                              

                                        if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())  {
                                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','You have successfully registered. Check your email address to activate your account.');
                                            //redirect('auth/register');
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','You have successfully given permitted Undercoverfunder to manage your wepay account.');
                                                //redirect('campaign');
                                            }
                                    }
                }
        }
        if(isset($_GET['error']))
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','You denied the request so your account is not activated.');
            //redirect('auth/register');
        }
    } //end function    

 }
```

Session.php :

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Session Class
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Sessions
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html
 */
class CI_Session {

    var $sess_encrypt_cookie        = FALSE;
    var $sess_use_database          = FALSE;
    var $sess_table_name            = '';
    var $sess_expiration            = 7200;
    var $sess_expire_on_close       = FALSE;
    var $sess_match_ip              = FALSE;
    var $sess_match_useragent       = TRUE;
    var $sess_cookie_name           = 'ci_session';
    var $cookie_prefix              = '';
    var $cookie_path                = '';
    var $cookie_domain              = '';
    var $cookie_secure              = FALSE;
    var $sess_time_to_update        = 300;
    var $encryption_key             = '';
    var $flashdata_key              = 'flash';
    var $time_reference             = 'time';
    var $gc_probability             = 5;
    var $userdata                   = array();
    var $CI;
    var $now;

    /**
     * Session Constructor
     *
     * The constructor runs the session routines automatically
     * whenever the class is instantiated.
     */
    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
        log_message('debug', "Session Class Initialized");

        // Set the super object to a local variable for use throughout the class
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        // Set all the session preferences, which can either be set
        // manually via the $params array above or via the config file
        foreach (array('sess_encrypt_cookie', 'sess_use_database', 'sess_table_name', 'sess_expiration', 'sess_expire_on_close', 'sess_match_ip', 'sess_match_useragent', 'sess_cookie_name', 'cookie_path', 'cookie_domain', 'cookie_secure', 'sess_time_to_update', 'time_reference', 'cookie_prefix', 'encryption_key') as $key)
        {
            $this->$key = (isset($params[$key])) ? $params[$key] : $this->CI->config->item($key);
        }

        if ($this->encryption_key == '')
        {
            show_error('In order to use the Session class you are required to set an encryption key in your config file.');
        }

        // Load the string helper so we can use the strip_slashes() function
        $this->CI->load->helper('string');

        // Do we need encryption? If so, load the encryption class
        if ($this->sess_encrypt_cookie == TRUE)
        {
            $this->CI->load->library('encrypt');
        }

        // Are we using a database?  If so, load it
        if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE AND $this->sess_table_name != '')
        {
            $this->CI->load->database();
        }

        // Set the "now" time.  Can either be GMT or server time, based on the
        // config prefs.  We use this to set the "last activity" time
        $this->now = $this->_get_time();

        // Set the session length. If the session expiration is
        // set to zero we'll set the expiration two years from now.
        if ($this->sess_expiration == 0)
        {
            $this->sess_expiration = (60*60*24*365*2);
        }

        // Set the cookie name
        $this->sess_cookie_name = $this->cookie_prefix.$this->sess_cookie_name;

        // Run the Session routine. If a session doesn't exist we'll
        // create a new one.  If it does, we'll update it.
        if ( ! $this->sess_read())
        {
            $this->sess_create();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->sess_update();
        }

        // Delete 'old' flashdata (from last request)
        $this->_flashdata_sweep();

        // Mark all new flashdata as old (data will be deleted before next request)
        $this->_flashdata_mark();

        // Delete expired sessions if necessary
        $this->_sess_gc();

        log_message('debug', "Session routines successfully run");
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Fetch the current session data if it exists
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  bool
     */
    function sess_read()
    {
        // Fetch the cookie
        $session = $this->CI->input->cookie($this->sess_cookie_name);

        // No cookie?  Goodbye cruel world!...
        if ($session === FALSE)
        {
            log_message('debug', 'A session cookie was not found.');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Decrypt the cookie data
        if ($this->sess_encrypt_cookie == TRUE)
        {
            $session = $this->CI->encrypt->decode($session);
        }
        else
        {
            // encryption was not used, so we need to check the md5 hash
            $hash    = substr($session, strlen($session)-32); // get last 32 chars
            $session = substr($session, 0, strlen($session)-32);

            // Does the md5 hash match?  This is to prevent manipulation of session data in userspace
            if ($hash !==  md5($session.$this->encryption_key))
            {
                log_message('error', 'The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be a possible hacking attempt.');
                $this->sess_destroy();
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        // Unserialize the session array
        $session = $this->_unserialize($session);

        // Is the session data we unserialized an array with the correct format?
        if ( ! is_array($session) OR ! isset($session['session_id']) OR ! isset($session['ip_address']) OR ! isset($session['user_agent']) OR ! isset($session['last_activity']))
        {
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Is the session current?
        if (($session['last_activity'] + $this->sess_expiration) < $this->now)
        {
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Does the IP Match?
        if ($this->sess_match_ip == TRUE AND $session['ip_address'] != $this->CI->input->ip_address())
        {
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Does the User Agent Match?
        if ($this->sess_match_useragent == TRUE AND trim($session['user_agent']) != trim(substr($this->CI->input->user_agent(), 0, 120)))
        {
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Is there a corresponding session in the DB?
        if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE)
        {
            $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $session['session_id']);

            if ($this->sess_match_ip == TRUE)
            {
                $this->CI->db->where('ip_address', $session['ip_address']);
            }

            if ($this->sess_match_useragent == TRUE)
            {
                $this->CI->db->where('user_agent', $session['user_agent']);
            }

            $query = $this->CI->db->get($this->sess_table_name);

            // No result?  Kill it!
            if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
            {
                $this->sess_destroy();
                return FALSE;
            }

            // Is there custom data?  If so, add it to the main session array
            $row = $query->row();
            if (isset($row->user_data) AND $row->user_data != '')
            {
                $custom_data = $this->_unserialize($row->user_data);

                if (is_array($custom_data))
                {
                    foreach ($custom_data as $key => $val)
                    {
                        $session[$key] = $val;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Session is valid!
        $this->userdata = $session;
        unset($session);

        return TRUE;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Write the session data
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  void
     */
    function sess_write()
    {
        // Are we saving custom data to the DB?  If not, all we do is update the cookie
        if ($this->sess_use_database === FALSE)
        {
            $this->_set_cookie();
            return;
        }

        // set the custom userdata, the session data we will set in a second
        $custom_userdata = $this->userdata;
        $cookie_userdata = array();

        // Before continuing, we need to determine if there is any custom data to deal with.
        // Let's determine this by removing the default indexes to see if there's anything left in the array
        // and set the session data while we're at it
        foreach (array('session_id','ip_address','user_agent','last_activity') as $val)
        {
            unset($custom_userdata[$val]);
            $cookie_userdata[$val] = $this->userdata[$val];
        }

        // Did we find any custom data?  If not, we turn the empty array into a string
        // since there's no reason to serialize and store an empty array in the DB
        if (count($custom_userdata) === 0)
        {
            $custom_userdata = '';
        }
        else
        {
            // Serialize the custom data array so we can store it
            $custom_userdata = $this->_serialize($custom_userdata);
        }

        // Run the update query
        $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
        $this->CI->db->update($this->sess_table_name, array('last_activity' => $this->userdata['last_activity'], 'user_data' => $custom_userdata));

        // Write the cookie.  Notice that we manually pass the cookie data array to the
        // _set_cookie() function. Normally that function will store $this->userdata, but
        // in this case that array contains custom data, which we do not want in the cookie.
        $this->_set_cookie($cookie_userdata);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Create a new session
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  void
     */
    function sess_create()
    {
        $sessid = '';
        while (strlen($sessid) < 32)
        {
            $sessid .= mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax());
        }

        // To make the session ID even more secure we'll combine it with the user's IP
        $sessid .= $this->CI->input->ip_address();

        $this->userdata = array(
                            'session_id'    => md5(uniqid($sessid, TRUE)),
                            'ip_address'    => $this->CI->input->ip_address(),
                            'user_agent'    => substr($this->CI->input->user_agent(), 0, 120),
                            'last_activity' => $this->now,
                            'user_data'     => ''
                            );


        // Save the data to the DB if needed
        if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE)
        {
            $this->CI->db->query($this->CI->db->insert_string($this->sess_table_name, $this->userdata));
        }

        // Write the cookie
        $this->_set_cookie();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Update an existing session
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  void
     */
    function sess_update()
    {
        // We only update the session every five minutes by default
        if (($this->userdata['last_activity'] + $this->sess_time_to_update) >= $this->now)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Save the old session id so we know which record to
        // update in the database if we need it
        $old_sessid = $this->userdata['session_id'];
        $new_sessid = '';
        while (strlen($new_sessid) < 32)
        {
            $new_sessid .= mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax());
        }

        // To make the session ID even more secure we'll combine it with the user's IP
        $new_sessid .= $this->CI->input->ip_address();

        // Turn it into a hash
        $new_sessid = md5(uniqid($new_sessid, TRUE));

        // Update the session data in the session data array
        $this->userdata['session_id'] = $new_sessid;
        $this->userdata['last_activity'] = $this->now;

        // _set_cookie() will handle this for us if we aren't using database sessions
        // by pushing all userdata to the cookie.
        $cookie_data = NULL;

        // Update the session ID and last_activity field in the DB if needed
        if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE)
        {
            // set cookie explicitly to only have our session data
            $cookie_data = array();
            foreach (array('session_id','ip_address','user_agent','last_activity') as $val)
            {
                $cookie_data[$val] = $this->userdata[$val];
            }

            $this->CI->db->query($this->CI->db->update_string($this->sess_table_name, array('last_activity' => $this->now, 'session_id' => $new_sessid), array('session_id' => $old_sessid)));
        }

        // Write the cookie
        $this->_set_cookie($cookie_data);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Destroy the current session
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  void
     */
    function sess_destroy()
    {
        // Kill the session DB row
        if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE && isset($this->userdata['session_id']))
        {
            $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $this->userdata['session_id']);
            $this->CI->db->delete($this->sess_table_name);
        }

        // Kill the cookie
        setcookie(
                    $this->sess_cookie_name,
                    addslashes(serialize(array())),
                    ($this->now - 31500000),
                    $this->cookie_path,
                    $this->cookie_domain,
                    0
                );

        // Kill session data
        $this->userdata = array();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Fetch a specific item from the session array
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function userdata($item)
    {
        return ( ! isset($this->userdata[$item])) ? FALSE : $this->userdata[$item];
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Fetch all session data
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  array
     */
    function all_userdata()
    {
        return $this->userdata;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Add or change data in the "userdata" array
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   mixed
     * @param   string
     * @return  void
     */
    function set_userdata($newdata = array(), $newval = '')
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => $newval);
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                $this->userdata[$key] = $val;
            }
        }

        $this->sess_write();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Delete a session variable from the "userdata" array
     *
     * @access  array
     * @return  void
     */
    function unset_userdata($newdata = array())
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => '');
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                unset($this->userdata[$key]);
            }
        }

        $this->sess_write();
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Add or change flashdata, only available
     * until the next request
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   mixed
     * @param   string
     * @return  void
     */
    function set_flashdata($newdata = array(), $newval = '')
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => $newval);
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                $flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':new:'.$key;
                $this->set_userdata($flashdata_key, $val);
            }
        }
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Keeps existing flashdata available to next request.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  void
     */
    function keep_flashdata($key)
    {
        // 'old' flashdata gets removed.  Here we mark all
        // flashdata as 'new' to preserve it from _flashdata_sweep()
        // Note the function will return FALSE if the $key
        // provided cannot be found
        $old_flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':old:'.$key;
        $value = $this->userdata($old_flashdata_key);

        $new_flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':new:'.$key;
        $this->set_userdata($new_flashdata_key, $value);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Fetch a specific flashdata item from the session array
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function flashdata($key)
    {
        $flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':old:'.$key;
        return $this->userdata($flashdata_key);
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Identifies flashdata as 'old' for removal
     * when _flashdata_sweep() runs.
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return  void
     */
    function _flashdata_mark()
    {
        $userdata = $this->all_userdata();
        foreach ($userdata as $name => $value)
        {
            $parts = explode(':new:', $name);
            if (is_array($parts) && count($parts) === 2)
            {
                $new_name = $this->flashdata_key.':old:'.$parts[1];
                $this->set_userdata($new_name, $value);
                $this->unset_userdata($name);
            }
        }
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Removes all flashdata marked as 'old'
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return  void
     */

    function _flashdata_sweep()
    {
        $userdata = $this->all_userdata();
        foreach ($userdata as $key => $value)
        {
            if (strpos($key, ':old:'))
            {
                $this->unset_userdata($key);
            }
        }

    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Get the "now" time
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return  string
     */
    function _get_time()
    {
        if (strtolower($this->time_reference) == 'gmt')
        {
            $now = time();
            $time = mktime(gmdate("H", $now), gmdate("i", $now), gmdate("s", $now), gmdate("m", $now), gmdate("d", $now), gmdate("Y", $now));
        }
        else
        {
            $time = time();
        }

        return $time;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Write the session cookie
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  void
     */
    function _set_cookie($cookie_data = NULL)
    {
        if (is_null($cookie_data))
        {
            $cookie_data = $this->userdata;
        }

        // Serialize the userdata for the cookie
        $cookie_data = $this->_serialize($cookie_data);

        if ($this->sess_encrypt_cookie == TRUE)
        {
            $cookie_data = $this->CI->encrypt->encode($cookie_data);
        }
        else
        {
            // if encryption is not used, we provide an md5 hash to prevent userside tampering
            $cookie_data = $cookie_data.md5($cookie_data.$this->encryption_key);
        }

        $expire = ($this->sess_expire_on_close === TRUE) ? 0 : $this->sess_expiration + time();

        // Set the cookie
        setcookie(
                    $this->sess_cookie_name,
                    $cookie_data,
                    $expire,
                    $this->cookie_path,
                    $this->cookie_domain,
                    $this->cookie_secure
        );
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Serialize an array
     *
     * This function first converts any slashes found in the array to a temporary
     * marker, so when it gets unserialized the slashes will be preserved
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   array
     * @return  string
     */
    function _serialize($data)
    {
        if (is_array($data))
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $val)
            {
                if (is_string($val))
                {
                    $data[$key] = str_replace('\\', '{{slash}}', $val);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (is_string($data))
            {
                $data = str_replace('\\', '{{slash}}', $data);
            }
        }

        return serialize($data);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Unserialize
     *
     * This function unserializes a data string, then converts any
     * temporary slash markers back to actual slashes
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   array
     * @return  string
     */
    function _unserialize($data)
    {
        $data = @unserialize(strip_slashes($data));

        if (is_array($data))
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $val)
            {
                if (is_string($val))
                {
                    $data[$key] = str_replace('{{slash}}', '\\', $val);
                }
            }

            return $data;
        }

        return (is_string($data)) ? str_replace('{{slash}}', '\\', $data) : $data;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Garbage collection
     *
     * This deletes expired session rows from database
     * if the probability percentage is met
     *
     * @access  public
     * @return  void
     */
    function _sess_gc()
    {
        if ($this->sess_use_database != TRUE)
        {
            return;
        }

        srand(time());
        if ((rand() % 100) < $this->gc_probability)
        {
            $expire = $this->now - $this->sess_expiration;

            $this->CI->db->where("last_activity < {$expire}");
            $this->CI->db->delete($this->sess_table_name);

            log_message('debug', 'Session garbage collection performed.');
        }
    }
}
// END Session Class

/* End of file Session.php */
/* Location: ./system/libraries/Session.php */
```

Comment: why don't you upgrade ?

Comment: @Amir im not own this site, the owner so far asking the error fix.

Comment: Please check if you have space before <?php, if yes then remove first